# Why is std::iterator_traits::value_type non-const even for a const_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, const-correctness, const-iterator, iterator-traits

In the C++ standard library, why is

```cpp
std::iterator_traits<const T*>::value_type
```

the same type as

```cpp
std::iterator_traits<T*>::value_type
```

Why it is designed like that? Shouldn't the first be `const T` and the second only `T`? How are you supposed to take the underlying const-correct type of an iterator? I know you can write your own template class and specialization and get it from

```cpp
std::iterator_traits<const T*>::pointer
```

but shouldn't there be a member typedef that holds it?

Comment: Could you explain "take the underlying const correct type"?  What do you mean by "take"?

Comment: I mean, if I want to get "const T" from the iterator or from iterator_traits as a member typedef, when the iterator is pointing to a const type.

Comment: I see.  I'm not sure what a good use case would be though.  Could you add an example?

Comment: Let's say you want to get the type iterator_traits<It>::value_type::some_member_const_dependent_type and you want it to be const if It is a const iterator.

Comment: The constness of T doesn't affect T::type, so having iterator_traits<it>::value_type be const wouldn't help there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It allows me to do this:

```
std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type val = *iter;
val += 5;
doSomething(val);
```

But that's harder if `value_type` is const, because I need to use `remove_const`.

If I don't want to get a modifiable value then it doesn't matter whether `value_type` is const or not:

```
const std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type cval = *iter;
std::iterator_traits<I>::reference        ref  = *iter;
```

Both of these work for const iterators and non-const iterators, and both work whether `value_type` is const or not, but the first example only works for const iterators if their `value_type` is non-const.

> How are you supposed to take the underlying const correct type of an iterator?

An iterator doesn't necessarily have an underlying type of its own, an iterator usually refers to some range or some collection, and that collection is what has an underlying type.  e.g `std::list<int>::const_iterator`'s `value_type` is `std::list<int>::value_type`, which is `int` not `const int`.

You don't necessarily want to know what the underlying type is anyway, it's more likely you want to know what the result of `*iter` is, and that's what `iterator_traits<I>::reference` tells you.

Comment: +1: That's a good example of why it is good for it not to be const.

Comment: I guess it is so, because it is far more useful, as you point in you examples.

Comment: Quote:
"An iterator doesn't necessarily have an underlying type of its own, an iterator usually refers to some range or some collection, and that collection is what has an underlying type."
"const T*" can refer to an iterator to collection of type "const T" or a const iterator to a collection of type "T". It seams there is no way to distinguish what you mean by "std::iterator_traits<const T*>", so it is "better" to assume, that you mean it is a const iterator.

Comment: It's better not to assume either, and have a consistent model that works for both.

Comment: I mean, that std::iterator_traits as is, assumes that "const T*" is a const iterator to a collection of type "T".

Comment: It doesn't "assume" anything, it is not intelligent. It tells you the type returned by `*iter` (called `reference`) and the type returned by `iter->` (called `pointer`) and the "value type" which by convention is not `const` even if the iterator is a const iterator.  That's just the way it is, partly because that is more useful in many situations, as shown in my answer above.

Answer (score 17):

Constness doesn't matter for the value type, since a value implies a copy.  The `std::iterator_traits<const T*>::reference` is a `const T&` however.

For example, you can write this function:

```
template <class Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type getValue(Iterator i)
{
  return *i;
}
```

and it works perfectly fine whether Iterator is a `const T *` or a `T *`.

Comment: That function would also work fine if `value_type` was `const T` :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: True.  I like your example.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: but would it make sense ? There are restrictions associated with `const` return types.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it might make sense for class types, without knowing what `value_type` is you can't say. The point is it works.