# map::const_iterator mapped type is not const

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an iterator adaptor for a class built on top of a map. I'm having issue when trying to get the mapped type from the iterator type. Basically I'd like to get:

- map<Key,Val>::iterator --> Val
- map<Key,Val>::const_iterator --> Val const

Here is a minimal repro.

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
    
template <typename BaseIteratorT>
using ValueType = typename BaseIteratorT::value_type::second_type;
    
// Passes
static_assert(
    std::is_same<ValueType<std::map<double, int>::iterator>, int>::value,
    "bad type for mutable iterator");

// Fails
static_assert(
    std::is_same<ValueType<std::map<double, int>::const_iterator>, const int>::value,
    "bad type for const iterator");
```

How can I achieve that (C++14)?

Comment: The issue in this code that `pair<A,B>::second_type` is always `B` , member typedefs don't morph according to constness

Comment: Why would you want `const val`? It makes no sense. If you wanted reference `val&` to `const val&` then it'd make sense but not value.

Comment: `value_type`  is the type not the reference type. So the constness doesn't matter to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For almost all practical purposes, types you might want to deduce is tied to some expression, in which case `decltype` is always the answer

```
template<typename T>
using mapped_type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype((std::declval<T>()->second))>;

using m = std::map<char, int>;
using i = mapped_type<m::iterator>  // int
using ci = mapped_type<m::const_iterator>  // const int
```

Answer (score 2):

The `value_type` of a `std::map` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.  The `second_type` of that pair is just `T`, not `const T`, not `const T&`, just `T`.  Dereferencing a `map::const_iterator` will return a `const pair&` reference, but that will not change that pair's `second_type` to `const`.  If you want that, detect whether the iterator's `value_type` is `const` or not, such as with `std::is_const`, and if so then apply `const` to its `second_type`, such as with [`std::add_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv).

Comment: you are right. Based on this I came with an implementation based on partial template specialization of a type for the iterator and const_iterator types. And another solution based on std::conditional and std::is_const. @PasserBy solution is even simpler.